# Why comparing matrices is not evaluated as boolean in Octave?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, octave

Im new to Octave and playing around with the console.

why when comparing matrices, the expression is not evaluates as boolean :

example:

```
>> A=[1,2;3,4];     % creating 2x2 matrix
>> 5 == 5           % sample comparison returns true (1)
ans = 1

>> A(1,1) == A(1,1) % single element comparison returns true (1)
ans = 1

>> A == A           % returns 2x2 matrix ???
ans =

  1  1
  1  1

>> size(A == A)     % prove that the above returns 2x2 matrix
ans =

   2   2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`==`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html) is for element-wise comparison of two matrices. To check whether two matrices are same or not, use [`isequal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sardar's answer is correct, but when it comes to computational time, I think that my alternative answer is better: You can as well check that all elements of the boolean matrix A == A are 1, i.e., that the sum of 1s in the matrix A==A equals the number of elements of A, i.e:

> > sum((A == A)(:)) == numel(A)
> >
> > ans =  1

Where the operator (:) simply vectorizes the matrix A==A so that it can be added with sum(). Compare the two answers when you matrix is quite big, for instance by defining A = rand(1e4), the computation time is considerably different...

Comment: It is easier to use `all`.